# How can I find which lines in a certain file are not started by lines from another file using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two text files, A and B:

A:

```
a start
b stop
c start
e start
```

B:

```
b
c
```

How can I find which lines in A are not started by lines from B using shell(bash...) command. In this case, I want to get this answer:

```
a start
e start
```

Can I implement this using a single line of command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
sed '/^$/d;s/^/^/' B | grep -vf - A
```

The `sed` command will take all non-empty lines (observe the `/^$/d` command) from the file `B` and prepend a caret `^` in front of each line (so as to obtain an anchor for `grep`'s regexp), and spits all this to `stdout`. Then grep, with the `-f` option (which means take all patterns from a file, which happens to be `stdin` here, thanks to the `-` symbol) and does an invert matching (thanks to the `-v` option) on file `A`. Done.

Comment: +1. I especially like `-f -`. Another way to get sed to ignore blank lines is: `sed -n '/[^[:space:]]/s/^/^/p'`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
sed 's/^/\^/g' B > C.tmp
grep -vEf C.tmp A
rm C.tmp
```

Comment: @sudo_O haha, I need to actually add in a bit about the start anchor

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a combination of `xargs`, `cat`, and `grep`

Save the first letters of each line into FIRSTLETTERLIST. You can do this with some `cat` and `sed` work.

The idea is to take the blacklist and then match it against the interesting file.

```
cat file1.txt | xargs grep ^[^[$FIRSTLETTERLIST]]
```

This is untested, so I won't guarantee it will work, but it should point you in the right direction.